# Blackberry 9000 getting HTTP error 406 When using WiFi

Tags: networking, blackberry, wifi, jde

So, I have a Blackberry 9000 application doing simple networking using HttpConnection.  Everything works fine normally, when I go to urls of the form:

http://url.com

But I've discovered that I need to test this in wifi only situations (that is, without a BES or equivalent in sight). After some digging, I discovered that I need to add:

;interface=wifi

To all of my URLS, of the form:

http://url.com;interface=wifi

However, I'm noticing that this does not actually work, it gives me back a HTTP error 406.  Which according to wiki is a:

406 Not Acceptable
    The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.[2]

Am I doing something completely wrong? Does Blackberry wrap wifi only requests in headers that require particularly formatted websites?

Answer (score 1):

As explained on [this page](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html#http), you also need add "deviceside=true" to the URL.

> To specify that the underlying TCP
>   connection should be opened directly
>   from the handheld, set this parameter
>   to "true". Specify "deviceside=false"
>   when receiving or sending data through
>   the BlackBerry MDS Connection Service.

So your full URL would be:

```
http://url.com;interface=wifi;deviceside=true
```